# Division with python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a question, how can I do a division with python whose condition is, if the result is an integer, print only the integer, if the result is a decimal number, if you can print with the corresponding decimals.
For example:

```
 division = 12/6
 print(division)
```

The output would have to be:

```
 2
```

The problem is that python does not print it like this, it prints it in the following way: 2.0 and interprets it as a float number

If the same variable is changed values, for example:

```
 division = 15/4
 print(division)
```

The output would have to be:

```
 3,75
```

If the result of the division includes decimals there would be no problem printing them like this.

I hope I have made myself understood, thank you very much in advance.

Comment: In Python 3 `/` has a float result. Use `//` if you want an integer result

Comment: have a look at this article: https://anh.cs.luc.edu/handsonPythonTutorial/float.html

Comment: Why do you care how it is printed? What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your own function to do this:

```
def divide(a,b):
    if a//b == a/b:
        return a//b
    return a/b

print(divide(12,6)) #2
print(divide(15,4)) #3.75
```